# What is the "right" name for this Diophantine equation? $ a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 + \dots + a_k x_k \equiv n\pmod h$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, terminology, diophantine-equations, linear-diophantine-equations

I am not able to find a clear answer to what is the right terminology to refer to this type of equation:
$$
a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 + \dots + a_k x_k \equiv n\pmod h\,.
$$
where $a_i,x_i,n,h(\neq0) \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Clearly this is a Diophantine equation as we can express the $\mathrm{mod}\ h$ as and extra term $\gamma\cdot h$ on the right/left hand side. But given the modular arithmetic, should this be called, to be more precise, a linear multivariable congruence equation? Or should this be called a linear modular Diophantine equation? Or a linear Diophantine equation in modular arithmetic?

Thanks!

Comment: "Linear congruence" seems sufficient to me.

Comment: @Greg Martin: thanks! whenever I search for just "linear congruence" I find equations in a single variable $a x = b \pmod c$. That's why I was adding the "multivariable" word, but maybe, as you say, it is not required.

Comment: Oh, I see. If I'm writing I would just say "linear congruence". But for searching, yes, "multivariable" might be a good addition.